# How to use python to connect to Postgresql RDS in Private subnet

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, amazon-rds, portforwarding, ssh-tunnel

I have my RDS(Postgresql) database in Private subnet.
I want to query this db using a Python Program
Is this possible ?
I have a bastion running SSM and I can easily connect to the bastion without any keys and then connect to the DB.
Is there a way of doing port forwarding in a python program ?

THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it very simple if you use the article  - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-port-forwarding-using-aws-system-manager-sessions-manager/

just run,

```
aws ssm start-session --target $INSTANCE_ID
```

this will create a connection to the ec2. After this you can run any python program by using psycopg2

```
import psycopg2 
connection = psycopg2.connect(user="joe",
                              password="joe",
                              host="######",
                              port="5432",
                              database="stackdb")
```

Just putting here as it might help someone